# Применение Autofac в консольном приложении C# .NET

Tags: c#, .net, шаблоны-проектирования, inversion-of-control, autofac

Решил пощупать на практике Autofac. Но не хватает знаний для его применения. Проект простой, взял за основу работу с последовательным портом. Создал модель

```
public class SerialPortSettings 
{ 
    public string Port { get; set; }
    public int BaudRate { get; set; }
    public int DataBits { get; set; }
    public Parity Parity { get; set; }
    public StopBits StopBits { get; set; }
    public string ThreadControl { get; set; }
    public int ReadTimeOut { get; set; }

    public SerialPortSettings()
    {
      // Инициализация свойств и присвоение настроек порта  
    }
}
```

Интерфейс

```
public interface ISerialPortService
{
    void SetPort();
    void WriteData(string msg);
    bool OpenPort();
    bool ClosePort();
}
```

Реализация (весь класс не буду приводить в рамках экономии места)

```
public class SerialPortService : ISerialPortService, IDisposable
{
    private SerialPortSettings _portSettings;
    private SerialPort _comPort;

    public TransmissionType CurrentTransmissionType { get; set; }
    public string RecievedText { get; set; }
    public string PortStatus { get; set; }

    public event DataRecievedEventHandler DataChanged;
    public delegate void DataRecievedEventHandler(object sender, string package);

    public SerialPortService()
    {
        _portSettings = new SerialPortSettings();
        _comPort = new SerialPort();
        _comPort.DataReceived += comPort_DataReceived;
    }
```

Ну и в мейн я просто работаю с объектами SerialPortService

```
class Program
{
    static SerialPortService portService = new SerialPortService();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        portService.OpenPort();
        Console.WriteLine(portService.PortStatus);
        Console.WriteLine(portService.RecievedText);
        Console.ReadKey();

        portService.ClosePort();
    }
```

Создал отдельный класс для настройки Autogac
и тут не понимаю как все это дело правильно настроить (а может я уже и так верно все сделал).

```
public class AutofacSetup
{
    public static void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<SerialPortService>()
            .As<ISerialPortService>();
        builder.Build();
    }
}
```

И что дальше с ним делать?

Comment: Погуглите [1](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/21.4.php) [2](https://habr.com/post/343830/) [3](https://metanit.com/sharp/mvc5/21.1.php), это ведь несложно

Comment: @PavelMayorov, моя ошибка. Поправил.

Comment: @KirillRunk у вас первая и третья ссылки все еще ведут на ASP.NET. Вторая лучше, но там нет никакой конкретики. Напомню, автор не может догадаться что ему делать с IContainer, чем ему поможет теория?

Comment: Вот именно, я просто не пойму как это настроить использовать. Допустим я настрою, потом мне что, просто в мейне дернуть метод AutofacSetup?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, теория нужна, что бы понимать, что делаешь не так на примере чужого кода. К примеру, в теории будет указано, что нужно пользоваться интерфейсами и указывать в конструкторах их. И то, что инициализация с `new` внутри конструктора - не есть корректно. Это позволит человеку: 1. увидеть по факту, как этим пользоваться и 2. отрефакторить свой код. разве нет?

Comment: @KirillRunk ну так где по вашим ссылкам он *"1. увидит по факту как этим пользоваться"* в консольном приложении-то?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, тут ваша правда :\

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно вернуть результат работы метода `Build()`:

```
public static IContainer ConfigureContainer()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

    builder.RegisterType<SerialPortService>()
        .As<ISerialPortService>();

    return builder.Build();
}
```

Теперь можно использовать контейнер для того чтобы достать из него сервисы:

```
var container = AutofacSetup.ConfigureContainer();
var service = container.Resolve<ISerialPortService>();
service.OpenPort();
```

Видите, насколько программа упростилась? <sup>*(это был сарказм)*</sup>

---

Для того, чтобы выгода от использования Autofac была ощутима, у вас должны быть классы с зависимостями. Много классов с зависимостями. Пока что у вас есть всего 1 класс в котором нет ни одной зависимости, так что польза от Autofac сомнительна.

Также напоминаю, что в нормальной архитектуре построенный контейнер не должен покидать пределы Composition Root (у вас в роли Сomposition Root выступает, скорее всего, метод Main).

Comment: Да, действительно. И теперь если еще расширять другими сервисами (например разные порты, протоколы и тд) Спасибо за ваш ответ! Выходит что в принципе я настроил верно и мне необходимо было использовать лишь RegisterType, ну и плюс вернуть из метода построенный контейнер?

Answer (score 1):

Замените

```
static SerialPortService portService = new SerialPortService();
```

на строчку:

```
private static ISerialPortService portService { get; set; }
```

А в Main добавьте вызов autofac. Он вам в portService будет подставлять на место абстрактного интерфейса ISerialPortService конкретную реализацию SerialPortService.

Я вообще предпочитаю Main держать чистым - поэтому вынес бы из него всю логику работы приложения, оставив только вызов autofac:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ConfigureContainer();

    Execute();
}

static void Execute()
{
    portService.OpenPort();
    Console.WriteLine(portService.PortStatus);
    Console.WriteLine(portService.RecievedText);
    Console.ReadKey();

    portService.ClosePort();
}
```

Код ConfigureContainer посмотрите в соседнем ответе, не буду переписывать одно и то же.

Comment: Зачем тут вообще `static`?