# Как правильно организовать ввод данных из консоли и их повторный перевод?

Tags: c#

Сделал тестовый переводчик на основе Яндекс апи, все переводит, сделал на основе консольного приложения .net core и контейнера Autofac. Но так как приложение консольное, то как-то не знаю как правильно организовать ввод данных из консоли и их повторный перевод. В примере только класс Program где логика запуска и работы, вопрос. Может как то можно эффективнее сделать?

Вот код:

```
using System;
using Autofac;

namespace Coretranslate
{
    class Program
    {
        // подключаем контейнер
        private static IContainer Container { get; set; }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Вас приветствует тестовый переводчик");
            // регистрируем наш функционал в контейнере
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
            builder.RegisterType<YandexTranslation>().Named<ITranslation>("Yandex");
            Container = builder.Build();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите текст для перевода");
            // читаем данные с консоли
            string temptext = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите направление перевода 1) ru-en 2) en-ru");
            var trans = Console.ReadLine();

                switch (trans)
                {
                    case "1":
                    var x = "ru-en";
                    Yandex(temptext, x);
                    break;
                    case "2":
                    string y = "en-ru";
                    Yandex(temptext, y);
                    break;

                    default:
                        Console.WriteLine("Еще перводить будите");
                        break;
                }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }

        public static void Yandex(string text,string lang)
        {
          using (var scope = Container.BeginLifetimeScope())
          {
                var Run = scope.ResolveNamed<ITranslation>("Yandex");
                Console.WriteLine( Run.Translate(text, lang));
          }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Почему у вас всё в main свалено в кучу, это разве "модульность"? Посмотрите [сюда](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/894661/213987), вынесите конфигурирование контейнеров в отдельный метод по аналогии. Это раз. Вынесите switch в отдельный метод, там же замените невнятные константы "1" и "2" на enum TranslationDirection { FromRuToEn, FromEnToRu }. Кроме того, по мере того, как у вас очистится от логики метод main вы сможете в нём написать бесконечный цикл while(true), в котором будет ввод данных для перевода, перевод, а потом _отдельный_ вопрос "будете переводить ещё", где и выходить из цикла.

Comment: @AK Спасибо за ответ, ценно ваше мнение

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch немного не в тему, но все же интересно: эти все вопросы - тестовые задания при трудоустройстве или просто для саморазвития?

Comment: @slippyk Да это тестовые задания и само развитие, ну и конечно я старюсь полученную теорию совместить с практикой, а лучший вариант это вот тестовые задания, Я по началу пробовал на простых вещах типа  Codewars, для новичков самое то, а потом уже хочется задач из реального мира. а тут тестовые задания. Ну и я начал техническое интервью проходить успешно благодаря тестам.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Что-то в духе:

```
public interface ITranslator
{
    string Translate(string inputText, TranslationDirection translationDirection);
}

public class YandexTranslator : ITranslator
{
    public string Translate(string inputText, TranslationDirection translationDirection)
    {
        throw new System.NotImplementedException();
    }
}

public enum TranslationDirection
{
    FromRuToEn = 1,
    FromEnToRu = 2,
}
```

Настройка контейнера:

```
public static class AutofacSetup
{
    public static IContainer ConfigureContainer()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.RegisterType<YandexTranslator>()
               .As<ITranslator>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

Ну и собственно, программа. Вот ответ на ваш вопрос, как спрашивать ещё перевод:

```
internal static class Program
{
    private static ITranslator Translator { get; set; }

    private static void Main()
    {
        var container = AutofacSetup.ConfigureContainer();
        Translator = container.Resolve<ITranslator>();

        while (true)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Введите текст для перевода");
            var inputText = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Введите направление перевода 1) ru-en 2) en-ru");
            var direction = Console.ReadLine();

            Translator.Translate(inputText, ToEnum(direction));

            Console.WriteLine("Будем переводить ещё текст?");
            var choiseAgain = Console.ReadLine();
            if (!string.Equals(choiseAgain, "Y"))
                break;
        }
    }

    private static TranslationDirection ToEnum(string direction)
    {
        switch (direction)
        {
            case "1":
                return TranslationDirection.FromRuToEn;
            case "2":
                return TranslationDirection.FromEnToRu;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(direction));
        }
    }
}
```

Пока понятно?

Идём дальше.

Если вам нужны будут именно строки "en-ru" для работы внутри переводчика - то можете на значения enum [добавить атрибуты](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13099834/5752652) `Display(Name="en-ru")` и использовать его. Оставляю вам на домашнюю работу.

Чтобы не дописывать при добавлении нового языка в двух местах (enum и switch) - заменяем на парсинг как в [этом вопросе](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16100/5752652). (Оставляю вам на самостоятельную проработку)

Там же нужно будет добавить обработку значений, которые не входят в enum. Подумайте сами, как вы это себе видите. Я бы в случае некорректных значений направлений перевода - просто переходил бы к вопросу "хотите ещё?".

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать, да что то подобное я и хотел.

Comment: @VladimrVladimirovoch Я убегал на совещание, поэтому не успел добавить ссылки на вопросы с подсказками. Добавил, посмотрите их.

Comment: Спасибо вам за ответ про енам да я примерно так и сдеал.